# Troubles on retracting pointer values

Tags: c++

My teacher have forced us to use the skeleton code and I am now dealing with a ***[struct] variable.

```
struct Node
{
    Thing thing; 
    int quantity = 1; 
    Node *next = nullptr;  
};
```

I have a map as followed

```
        Node ***map = new Node**[width];
        Node **temp = new Node*[height];
        for (int i = 0; i<width; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<height; j++){
                Node* head = NULL; 
                Node* second = NULL; 
                Node* third = NULL; 
                head = new Node(); 
                second = new Node(); 
                third = new Node(); 
                head->next = second; 
                second->next = third; 
                third->next = NULL;
                temp[j] = head;
            }
            map[i] = temp;
```

but I start crashing while I tried to get the value of map[0][2]->thing in a for loop, the whole loop is looking like this (thing is an enum btw)

```
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<width; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j<height; j++){
                if (map[i][j]->thing == 0||map[i][j]->thing==5||map[i][j]->thing==6) count = count + map[i][j]->quantity;
                cout<<map[i][j]->thing<<endl;
    }
                
    if (count>1)         
    cout << "There are "<< count <<" monsters left in the world!"<< endl;
    else if (count = 1)
    cout << "There is still one more monster left!"<< endl;
```

can someone explains to me why this is happening and how can I do the same thing without crashing with some example codes?

Comment: Seeing a triple pointer here is not a good sign. That seems overly indirect.

Comment: This would be way easier with a `std::vector` but if that's not an option because reasons then you'll need to manage that memory yourself. This code looks incomplete.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]  that reproduces the problem.   There isn't enough here for us to tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @tadman thank you for the suggestion but yeah i can't ; w ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code do you give `map[0][2]` a value so a crash is no surprise

Take a look,

```
map[i] = temp;
```

so therefore `map[0]` is equal to `temp`. Now look for `temp[2]` where is that given a value? Nowhere, so therefore `map[0][2]` has no value.

**EDIT** well the posted code has now been editted so that `temp[2]` is given a value. But the error below is still happening.

The other serious error is that you give every `map[i]` **the same value** `temp`. I'm sure that's not what you want.

Looking at your code I think (I'm not sure) that you are trying to do something like this

```
    Node ***map = new Node**[width];
    for (int i = 0; i<width; i++){
        map[i] = new Node*[height];
        for (int j = 0; j<height; j++){
            Node* head = new Node(); 
            Node* second = new Node(); 
            Node* third = new Node(); 
            head->next = second; 
            second->next = third; 
            third->next = NULL;
            map[i][j] = head;
        }
    }
```

That (untested) code constructs a 2D array of three element lists.

Comment: Yes this does solve my problem. Thank you very much  ^ ^'''. I am new to pointer so I am still a little confuse about how it works. I will study this code and check what I get wrong thanks a lot man :3